# Select | Copy AutoFiltered Range with Merged Cells -> Paste to A1 of NewSheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am need of help in regards to - Filtering a dynamically sized row count and then selecting the visible cells and pasting or inserting their values at the position of the original in a new sheet.

I have tried various different methods such as Copy, AutoFilter.Range but can not get a proper copy as I have merged cells in my sheet.

```
Sub HondaFilter()
Dim MainSheetOEE As Worksheet
Set MainSheetOEE = Worksheets("OEE Report")
Dim HondaOEE As Worksheet
Dim FilterRange As Range
MainSheetOEE.AutoFilterMode = False
With MainSheetOEE.Range("C:C")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=Array("Civic", "CRV", "Pilot", "MDX", "Mini Van", "Ridgeline"), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
Set HondaOEE = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HondaOEE")
Set DataPasteLocation = HondaOEE.Range("A1")
MainSheetOEE.AutoFilter.Range.Copy Destination:=DataPasteLocation
End Sub
Runtime Error: 1004 - We can't do that to a merged cell
```

Is there a way to just send the visible rows value to a new sheet ?? Formatting isnt an issue I can reformat everything afterwards - Cheers

EDIT --- I should make a note that

```
MainSheetOEE.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Does not provide a solution - as the sheet I am copying from has merged cells.

Comment: You can use [`Range.SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) and `xlCellTypeVisible` to work with visible cells.

Comment: @BigBen I tried that - I still got the error "Can't Do that with merged cells"

My header row is what contains all the titles and there are a couple merged cell locations in a static set of columns (IE always gunna be located in Column 2,3,5)

Comment: You can still work with `Range.SpecialCells` and `xlCellTypeVisible`. Instead of copying, you can loop through all visible rows and move individual lines over, testing for a merged cell. But this is a great demonstration of why merged cells should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for your advice Ben, I appreciate the help. Unfortunately, the generated file is created that way - I wish this wasn't the circumstance but I have thought of a few solutions. You'll probably see me on stack exchange again! Cheers,

Comment: Yeah, makes sense if that's the way the report is generated. Happy coding!